# muliselect dropdown with checkbox in php

Tags: php, jquery, dropdown

I am using php and i want to display a dropdown with checkbox using jquery. I referred this link http://phpzag.com/demo/multi-select-dropdown-with-checkbox-using-bootstrap-jquery-and-php/

and implemented with my data. But it is not working for me. The following is my code,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#test_namelist').multiselect({       
        nonSelectedText: 'Select testname'              
    });
});
</script>
```

dropdown options will come from my mysql db. values will be more than 2000.

Now i getting the following in console when click the dropdown,

```
[Violation] 'click' handler took 548ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 540ms
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: For 2000 options, I would recommend, instead of dropdown, go with autocomplete because such huge dropdown might result in browser crash & slowness.

Comment: Not to mention that most people won't like going through a multiselect dropdown with over 2000 options to select. And then there's your server that actually has to do something with all those options..

Comment: I suggest you to go through jquery chosen select plugin.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I will check